# Scraping calendar data for WinRT app development

Tags: calendar, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing an app for WinRT tablet which requires data from Windows8 Calendar app .
I am trying to use Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments api of win 8.1 preview .
Will it help ?  What other api's can be helpful to me to extract data of a user from his calendar ?

Answer (score 0):

The Appointments API is designed to provide a way to manage appointments on the user's calendar without granting access directly to that data. The app can manage the appointments that it sourced, for instance, but cannot delete arbitrary appointments.

Otherwise the Calendar app doesn't provide open access; the user's calendar that's associated with their live ID can be accessed through the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx), although that will be limited to just their Live calendar data and not other associated calendars.